# Deep linking: How to return to the app from which the deep link was called?

Tags: android, deeplink

Is it possible to track the origin of a deep link into an app?
In my project, I’m successfully deep linking from the browser into my app, completing what I need to do, and then am wanting to be sent back to the browser. However, calling `finish()` doesn’t work because, for some reason, my home screen is the activity in the stack between my browser (where I clicked the deep link) and my app, so I end up just getting put back on my phone’s home screen.

My thought was to somehow identity the “caller” of the deep link. Is there a way to do this without passing, say, the user agent in the query params of the deep link?

Where I'm at right now is as follows:

```
var browser = "com.android.chrome"
var intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(browser)
startActivity(intent)
```

But, obviously, I'd need to know the name of the package of the browser they came from.

(Or if anyone knows why my deep link may be going [browser -> home screen -> app] instead of [browser -> app], that would also be helpful.)

This is the activity stack just before calling `finish()`, from running `adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i run`:

```
 Running activities (most recent first):
        Run #0: ActivityRecord{50a3a82 u0 io.myapp/.activity.ActivityMain t6634}
    Running activities (most recent first):
        Run #0: ActivityRecord{b13082f u0 com.teslacoilsw.launcher/.NovaLauncher t6481}
    Running activities (most recent first):
        Run #0: ActivityRecord{c974ad u0 com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main t6607}
```

Where `com.teslacoilsw.launcher/.NovaLauncher` is my homescreen.